# System of differential equations blow-up in finite time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following system of differential equations:

$\begin{cases}y_1'=y_1(y_2-1)\\y_2'=y_2(y_1-1)\end{cases}$

with critical points $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$.

We can obtain the orbits:

$\dfrac{dy_1}{dy_2}=\dfrac{y_1}{y_2}\dfrac{y_2-1}{y_1-1}\Rightarrow \left(1-\dfrac{1}{y_1}\right)dy_1=\left(1-\dfrac{1}{y_2}\right)dy_2\Rightarrow y_1-\log(y_1)=y_2-\log(y_2)+C\Rightarrow $$y_1-\log(y_1)-1=y_2-\log(y_2)-1+C$.

Now we can define $h:(0,+\infty)\to\Bbb R$ as $h(t)=t-\log(t)-1$, so each orbit is contained in a curve of the form $\{(y_1,y_2):h(y_1)-h(y_2)=C\}$.

$h$ attains a minimum, $h(1)=0$, and it kind of behaves like a parabola, so we can define $h_1=h_{\mid (0,1)}$ and $h_2=h_{\mid (1,+\infty)}$, and they both are invertible maps with range $(0,+\infty)$.

I'm interested in the case $C=0$, which consists of a curve containing $(1,1)$, and more specifically, when $y_1(0)=y_{10}>0, y_2(0)=y_{20}>0$. In this case we have $y_2=h_2^{-1}(h(y_1))$ (or $y_1=h_2^{-1}(h(y_2))$). I've been told that there exists $0<\beta<+\infty$ such that $y_1(t),y_2(t)\xrightarrow{t\to\beta^-}+\infty$, but why is $\beta<+\infty$? Any ideas on how to show this?

---

The going-to-infinity part I think I can show: It's clear that $0<\beta\leq+\infty$, and we have $y_1(t),y_2(t)>1\;\forall t\geq0$, so both $y_1$ and $y_2$ are strictly increasing, and therefore $\exists\, a,b$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\beta^-}y_1(t)=a\in(y_{10},+\infty)$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\beta^-}y_2(t)=b\in(y_{20},+\infty)$.

If we had $a<+\infty$ then $b=\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\beta^-}y_2(t)=\lim_{t\to\beta^-}h_2^{-1}(h(y_1(t)))=h_2^{-1}(h(a))=a$ (because $a>y_{10}>1$). But then, as a consequence of LaSalle's invariance principle, $(a,a)$ should be a critical point, which is absurd. Therefore, $y_1(t)\xrightarrow{t\to\beta^-}+\infty$, and consequently, $y_2(t)\xrightarrow{t\to\beta^-}+\infty$.